# How to find similar posts?

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have PHP+MySQL. I'm looking through the `title` column to find most similar strings.

How can I find most similar strings in the database and and order them by similarity?

Comment: As I see 'LIKE' will show me exactly strings wich contains my string, but I need something like this: "Hi, my friend. How are you" is similar to "You are my friend".(4/4 words are from my string) "My friend is Mike" is less similar because it contains 3/4 words from my string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PHP function [levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) to get the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the strings.

Levenshtein distance is a measure of how different the strings are (and inversely, how similar). Imagine you have 3 strings:

- See spot run
- Watch spot run
- Hello my name is John

Using Levenshtein distance, we get the results:

```
See spot run - See spot run: 0
See spot run - Watch spot run: 5
See spot run - Hello my name is John: 17

Watch spot run - See spot run: 5
Watch spot run - Watch spot run: 0
Watch spot run - Hello my name is John: 18

Hello my name is John - See spot run: 17
Hello my name is John - Watch spot run: 18
Hello my name is John - Hello my name is John: 0
```

As you can see, more similar strings have a lower Levenshtein distance. This solution is not always practical, because you have to store the result between every string you wish to compare. So if you already have 1000 records, when you create a new record you have to get the result for the new string compared to every other string. You can then use these scores in your SQL query.

This may not be the best solution for you, but since nobody had mentioned it I thought I would.

You can also look at some other interesting PHP functions for string similarity:

- [similar_text](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) — Calculate the similarity between two strings
- [soundex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php) — Calculate the soundex key of a string

Answer (score 0):

You should use SELECT LIKE query [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html) is some docs on it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use LIKE in SQL query:

```
WHERE column_name LIKE '%string%'
```

You can replace empty spaces with "%" to make it more effective. I wouldn't call it the right way but considering your question that should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you really want to do but i think you're looking for query which find the most similar text in title column.

If it's true it can help:

**SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable where table LIKE '%searchedText%'
```

In this case `%` means that you find things which contains your `searchedText`